# Add cropping option to an image form

Tags: 7, forms, media

I've the next form.

```
$form['imagen'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Image'),
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpeg jpg png gif')),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://',
        '#progress_indicator' => 'throbber',
        '#status' => FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT,
        '#progress_message' => 'One moment while we save your file...',
    );
```

That generates something like this:

[image]

What I need is to give the user the option to see the image that he has upload, and resize the image. The functionality that I need, is the same that the [ImageField_crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop) module gives.

I'm totally lost. I don't know how to add this functionality to the form.
It's totally necessary for the project to insert this form in a custom module, because I have a multistep form.

Does anybody know how to do this??

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is displaying a working Field Widget Form on its own possible?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/is-displaying-a-working-field-widget-form-on-its-own-possible)

Comment: To get an explanation of the problem please read this comment https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/77916/43117

Comment: I don't get it. You say you need exact the same functionality as the contrib module X provides. Why don't you simply look into module X' code yourself? Then you'll know how they've done it and how you have to do it, no?

Answer (score 0):

Better you can go with implementing the field with "imagefield_crop" module instead of doing customization further.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible by adding the #widget attribute to the form?
Something like:

```
    $form['imagen'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpeg jpg png gif')),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#progress_indicator' => 'throbber',
    '#status' => FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT,
    '#progress_message' => 'One moment while we save your file...',
    '#widget' => array(
     'type' => 'imagefield_crop_widget',
  ),
);
```

Comment: I've never come across a `#widget` property, it's not listed in the [API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) so I guess this is something a contrib/custom module provides? Could you give some more information about where this property comes from and how it can be used?

Comment: Field API uses widget, so it might be a good thing to look into it? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7

Comment: Yep I'm (very) familiar with the field API - can you point me to the documentation for this `#widget` property? It doesn't occur in the form API docs, the docs you linked to, or the entire Drupal 7 codebase. I'm pretty positive it doesn't exist, but I'm curious as to where you've got the idea that it does from? Have you read something that says this exists or are you just literally guessing?

Comment: Clive, yes it's a guess since field api is using widget on fields. On the link I gave, it states "widget (array)" on the instance. So probably creating a custom field is the best solution for OP's problem?

Comment: I've found the next definition of field and field instance: [link](http://dikini.net/31.08.2010/entities_bundles_fields_and_field_instances). According to this both have widget option, but the code that kevin has show doesnt't work for me. It doesn't recognize "#widget" option. So, do I need to install any module??